# Problems with pointers and array

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, gmp

Posting this question after 3-4 days of frantic online search but nothing helped. Honestly, at this point I think I don't even know what to search for anymore. I really need some "pointers" on how to deal with pointers and arrays, this thing is killing me.

I am simply trying to compute integer exponentiation using binary exponentiation method. Here is my code for computing 2^n as example -

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gmp.h>

// Compute z = x^n
void mpz_binexp_pow(mpz_t z, const mpz_t x, const mpz_t n) {

/*
 * Local variables
 */
    char *pointer = NULL;
    char *pc = NULL;
    char *c = NULL;

    pointer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(mpz_t));
    pc = pointer;

/*
 *  Get the binary representation of the exponent
 */
    c = mpz_get_str(pointer,2,n);
    c[strlen(c)+1] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n\n",c);

/*
 *  Perform left to right binary exponentiation steps
 */
    /*for(int i = 0;i<strlen(c);i++) {
        mpz_pow_ui(z, z, 2);
        if (c[i] == '1')
            mpz_mul(z, z, x);
        printf("%c - \n", c[i]);
        //gmp_printf("%Zd\n", z);
    }*/

    while(*c){
        mpz_pow_ui(z, z, 2);
        if (*c == '1')
            mpz_mul(z, z, x);
        c++;
        printf("%c - \n", *c);
        //gmp_printf("%Zd\n", z);
    }

    free(pc);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

mpz_t z;    mpz_init(z);    mpz_set_ui(z,1);
mpz_t x;    mpz_init(x);    mpz_set_ui(x,2);
mpz_t n;    mpz_init(n);    mpz_set_ui(n,1449728);
mpz_binexp_pow(z,x,n);

return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine for small exponents like 2, 3 etc.. but things really get crazy for relatively larger numbers like the one shown(I need this to work for way larger exponents than what I show here)

Now when I run this code multiple times I get the right output only about 1 in 15 executions which I think doesn't really matter. I am not able to figure out what is going wrong. I get the right binary rep. of the exponent which I can see by printing it out. For example, the binary rep. of exponent 1449728 is 101100001111100000000. Now, when I get inside the loop to perform l2r steps, almost every time the program gets messed up after the third zero in the last zero sequence i.e it executes correctly until 1011000011111000**this point**. Sometimes I see some other characters like '?' and '>' instead of the rest of the zeros and sometimes I just don't see anything, the program gets stuck. What is going on?

I am very certain this is a pointer issue and my pointer knowledge is extremely weak but I would really like hints on how to fix this and also the reasoning behind what is happening and what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT**
This question has been resolved. I wish for this question to be closed or removed.

Comment: You don't malloc enough space. Read the documentation of `mpz_get_str` to see how to use it properly

Comment: If you want it to be removed, then use the delete link below the tags and remove it.